# Maintaining several log4j.xml configurations for multiple webapps

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, logging, log4j

Currently we have multiple (10+) webapps in Tomcat, each of them has to have its own log4j.xml configuration, because

- each webapp has a different file name for DailyRollingFileAppender
- there are often 2-3 appenders (info/error log, audit, statistics)
- on top of may have unique logger level definitions to reduce certain chatty components.

The growing challenge is that different parties, who use the logging, want different formats, rules and log levels:

- developers want TRACE logging for everything, testers want INFO logging, sys admins (for production deploys and so on) want an ERROR level only
- both developers and testers are happy with DailyRollingFileAppender, while sys admins want to use a logrotate instead
- sys admins want to zip the logs, which is inconvenient for developers and testers.

So the most obvious solution is of course to have log4j.xml in 3 variants (log4j.xml.dev, log4j.xml.test, log4j.xml.prod) for each webapp and redeploy the corresponding one somehow. Which looks like a nightmare to maintain or even setup.

Another option to have some location outside of webapps where there will be 1 log4j.xml for all webapps, which is setup once for that environment and not redeployed every time. Seems better, but that big log4j.xml can get messy, and I didn't find any recommendations on whether this is generally a good approach or where the log4j.xml should be placed in such case.

So if someone had a similar dilemma, how did you solve it? if you used one of the approaches above, or if you have an idea for the entirely different approach - I'd like to hear it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other posters with the same question, I will post an answer here, which is not ideal, but provides a partial solution, at least for us.

- Migrate to [log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). It provides better control on how you rotate the logs and allows to zip them up
- Create 2 log4j configurations: one for debugging and one for production. We use Maven for builds and releases, so Maven's profile controls which log4j model will be added to the webapp: build profile will pick up a debug/extended config, while release will pick up a reduced production config:

  ```
  <profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>logDebug</id>
      <activation>
          <property>
              <name>!release</name>
          </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <log4j.xml>log4jDebug.xml</log4j.xml>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>logRelease</id>
      <activation>
          <property>
              <name>release</name>
              <value>true</value>
          </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <log4j.xml>log4jRelease.xml</log4j.xml>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  ```

And then:

```
<build>   
  ...  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <echo message="Use log4j configuration file ${log4j.xml}" />
              <copy tofile="${project.build.directory}/classes/log4j.xml" overwrite="true">
                <fileset dir="src/main/resources/">
                  <include name="${log4j.xml}" />
                </fileset>
              </copy>
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested or worth to look at **Logstash**:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html

Comment: Thanks. It is seems mainly for monitoring / processing existing logs, but I don't see how it can help configuring logs. Could you be a bit more specific (sorry if I am asking something obvious, I never used Logstash)?